# TypeError: start_end_period() got an unexpected keyword argument 'months'

Tags: python

```
TypeError: start_end_period() got an unexpected keyword argument 'months'
```

I am struggling with this error. As it is possible to do `relativedelta.relativedelta(test)`, where something could be directly `months=1` of `years=1`, I would like to pass `test` directly as argument to `start_end_period()` method.

```
start_date = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__gte=entry_date_production).first().user.date_joined
def start_end_period(period):
                start = start_date - relativedelta.relativedelta(period)
                end = start + relativedelta.relativedelta(period - 1)
                return start, end
```

How could I adapt this method so that it will work with a single argument or a keyword argument, because both `relativedelta(7)` and `relativedelta(months=1)` are good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't pass months or years to a function which takes period, but does not take days, months, or years. Declare the function as taking what you want it to take.

Then you will need to passing them on to the relativedelta constructor. Here's the easiest way

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def start_end_period(start_date, days=0, months=0, years=0):
    period = relativedelta(days=days, months=months, years=years)
    start = start_date - period
    end = start + period + relativedelta(days=1)
    return start, end

import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(year=2017, month=3, day=1)
print (start_date)

print (start_end_period(start_date, days=7))
print (start_end_period(start_date, months=2))
print (start_end_period(start_date, years=1))
```

However, you should instead use **kwargs, which will automatically support all of relativedelta's options by passing on whatever was given to the function.

```
def start_end_period(start_date, **kwargs):
    period = relativedelta(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Since dateutil.relativedelta is an established downloadable module, I'll assume you are happy with their rules for adding variable sized dates. There are risks to the concept of using months as a diff, but the real rule is never do your own date related code, and using dateutil satisfies that, at least.